# Binding function to null

Tags: javascript

```
function f() {
  return this.x
}
f = f.bind(null)
f() // undefined
x = 1
f() // 1
```

I cannot find any page where it says that binding to `null` or `undefined` has no effect. Everywhere it is written that `this` becomes a link to the first argument of `bind`, exceptions are not mentioned. Can somebody provide a link to somewhere describing such behaviour?

Comment: Why would you even attempt to `.bind(null)` in the first place?  It seems like it's defeating the whole purpose of using `.bind()`.

Comment: Can this help: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#binding-exceptions

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "no effect" .. it clearly has the effect of returning the value of `x` which is not inside the scope of `f()` at all.

Comment: @BlagoEreš The link describes how it works correctly, but it's not the spec of js. My purpose is to find this behaviour specified by whoever makes js rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to the paragraph](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3), where this effect is specified. The problem was, falsey `this` is replaced with global object not while binding, but at the moment of bound function call.

Comment: Link provided is dead.

Comment: It works, maybe transient. Following up on the rules, statement from the question that binding to `null` has no effect is wrong. In particular, `f.bind({x: 2})` and `f.bind(null).bind({x: 2})` will yield different results, as binding to `null` has already fixed `this` to `window`.

Answer (score 8):

This behavior is different between strict mode and non-strict mode.

In non-strict mode, if you set `thisArg` to be `null` or `undefined`, `this` will be coerced to the global object (`window`).

In strict mode, `this` could be `null`, you will got an error.

```
function f() {
  'use strict';
  return this.x
}
f = f.bind(null)
f() // TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null
```

Comment: I see, but the question is, where is it written? I bet it's not just what you noticed at some point. I cannot find anything like that, for example here http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/ it says "set the [[BoundThis]] internal property of F to the value of thisArg," and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

The way that f() is being called in your example (a simple call) "this" refers to the global object (window) unless bound to something else. Binding in non-strict mode will only work with a truthy value i.e. binding to null or undefined is ignored and "this" remains bound to window.

That's why the assignment of 1 to x (without var keyword x is global, i.e. window.x) causes the function to return 1. Annotating your example:

```
function f() {
  return this.x
}
f = f.bind(null) // no effect in non-strict mode
f() // returns window.x (undefined)
x = 1 // window.x = 1
f() // returns window.x (1)
```

Binding to something that is truthy works e.g.

```
function f () { return this.x };
var y = { x: 42 };
var z = f.bind(y);
z(); // 42
```

However if you use strict mode, a binding of null or undefined *will* take effect.

```
function f () { "use strict"; return this.x; }
var z = f.bind(null); z(); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null
z = f.bind(); z(); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
z = f.bind({x:42}); z(); // 42
z = f.bind({x:"foo"}); z(); // "foo"
```